# Input Data Type of K-Means Clustering Method in OpenCV (vector<Mat>)

Tags: c++, opencv, k-means

I have been working on MNIST Dataset to classify the handwritten digit images. I can read the images and calculate histograms of them. Then, I pushed back Mat of histograms into vector. I could not implement K-Means Clustering Algorithm method (kmeans()) because the first argument of method(InputArray) leads to some error

OpenCV 3.0 has been used.

```
vector<Mat> histogram_list;


//some implementations


int clusterCount = 10;
Mat labels, centers;
int attempts = 5;
kmeans(samplingHist(histogram_list, h_bins, s_bins), clusterCount, labels,
    TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10000, 0.0001),
    attempts, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
```

Is there any advice to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

mat.int.hpp file. The error about assertion failed something.... and it returns me to that piece of code.

```
template<typename _Tp> inline_Tp& Mat::at(int i0, int i1) {
CV_DbgAssert(dims <= 2);
CV_DbgAssert(data);
CV_DbgAssert((unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0]);
CV_DbgAssert((unsigned)(i1 * DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1] * channels()));
CV_DbgAssert(CV_ELEM_SIZE1(DataType<_Tp>::depth) == elemSize1());
return ((_Tp*)(data + step.p[0] * i0))[i1];
```

}

I try to solve the problem with sampling to Mat from vector. However it could not help to solve it.  Where do I make a mistake?

```
Mat samplingHist(vector<Mat> &vec, int h, int s) {
    Mat samples(vec.size(), h * s, CV_32F);
    for (int k = 0; k < vec.size(); k++)
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < s; x++)
                samples.at<float>(k, y* s + x) = vec[k].at<float>(y, x);
    return samples;
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: which opencv version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong parameters. The documentation of says `InputArray data` must be of type `Mat` or at least `std::vector<cv::Point2f>`, not `std::vector<Mat>`.

Take a look at this example:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d63/kmeans_8cpp-example.html

Comment: I tried to solve it with sampling but does not work.